# NodeJs require('../file.js') issues

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to build a nodeJs app with express, sequelize and and sqlite. So in my root directory i have a routers directory where i store
'.js' files of express's routers. And again in root directory i have a 'db.js' file.
The problem is, when i try to require "db.js" file from the routers folder's '.js' files. it says

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'db.js'
```

I'm using require as in the example below

```
    db = require('../db.js');
```

Can someone help me find my mistake? Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root directory is where you start the app by calling node on that js file.

if the file is on the root of that file, you need to write

```
var db = require('./db'); // same file as yours.
```

using `'../'` will go to the parent folder and look there.

using `'db'` directly will look in the node_modules for the db module.

Answer (score 1):

Your current directory isn't what you think it is, so "../" is failing to go where you think it should.  Try something like this:

```
db = require('path').join(__dirname,'../db.js')
```

Here is the info on [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) and [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path).